# Implementing interface from alertdialog to fragment

Tags: android

I have fragment..And there is Alert dialog inside my fragment.When i click ok(positive button) new request must be sent to server...I have Ready class for making request to server
I send requests like this:
[image]

and my in my Get_document(Request making class) in onResponse response is sent to fragment through Interface:
[image]

and my question is What should I use inspite of this for implementing Interface in my fragment

Comment: You can create new instance of an interface insteadn of `this`.

Comment: How..?But I should use interface when response came.to my Get_document class...

Comment: When you pass this, your origin class should implement an interface. Alternatively you can pass new instance of and interface. Like.. you can replace `this` with `new ResponceListener {...}`

Comment: I think This is working.  @Wizard

Comment: Haha.. It always works.